# Laravel social getting gender and DOB

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

I'm using laravel social. I want gender and DOB from Google plus api , facebook, and twitter . Laravel by default give me only name,avatar,etc but not providing gender and DOB

Comment: show us what you have done so far

Comment: public function redirectToProvider() { return Socialite::driver('google')->redirect(); }
public function handleProviderCallback() { $user = Socialite::driver('google')->user(); }